# Optimal algorithm for adding markup tags to a text

Tags: algorithm, parsing, data-structures, trie, lexer

I have a dictionary that contains terms that I'd like to identify in a string.  For example, I'd like to ideally add an XML tag around my term `<highlight>term</highlight>`

Example

```
dictionary = ['Steve', 'Woz']
input = "I met Steve and Woz]
output = "I met <highlight>Steve</highlight> and <highlight>Woz</highlight>"
```

It can be more complicated since I need to identify each entry in the text so some of the highlights can be contained in another

For example

```
dictionary = ['Steve', 'Steve Jobs', 'Jobs']
input = "I met Steve Jobs]
output = "I met <highlight><highlight>Steve</highlight> <highlight>Jobs</highlight></highlight>"
```

I can store the dictionary in an Aho-Corasick trie and efficiently identify the keywords. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to efficiently tag the terms properly.

What would be the optimal way of performing this tagging?

Comment: you're using python?

Comment: @kpie any language would work. I am mostly interested in the right algorithm

Comment: Are you looking for an "optimal" way to do it, or just *any* way to do it? The Aho-Corasick algorithm can give you the starting point of the found term, and since you know the term's length you can easily add the start and beginning and ending tags. That seems pretty simple, so I'm wondering what your question is. My suggestion is to make it work, then worry about making it fast.

Comment: Are your terms multiword or singleword? Is there a pattern that they all follow?